Query | Rollup data for 24 hours with 5 mins interval even if data is not present then consider previous value in SQL
I have a tsdb_events table




event_id
event_name
event_time
updated_at
tenant
device
network
mobility_gateway
CAP




13
Attach Complete
2024-05-06 15:25:25.150 +0530
2024-05-06 15:25:25.156 +0530
XYZ
1
Dummy-NW-1
Dummy MG-1
1234aaaa


65
Detach
2024-05-06 15:25:44.879 +0530
2024-05-06 15:25:44.884 +0530
XYZ
1
Dummy-NW-1
Dummy MG-1
1234aaaa


5e
Detach
2024-05-06 18:24:20.093 +0530
2024-05-06 18:24:20.162 +0530
XYZ
1
Dummy-NW-1
Dummy MG-1
1234aaaa


89
Detach
2024-05-06 18:25:40.193 +0530
2024-05-06 18:25:40.205 +0530
XYZ
1
Dummy-NW-1
Dummy MG-1
1234aaaa


30
Detach
2024-05-06 18:25:52.611 +0530
2024-05-06 18:25:52.625 +0530
XYZ
1
Dummy-NW-1
Dummy MG-1
1234aaaa


e4
Detach
2024-05-06 18:26:33.843 +0530
2024-05-06 18:26:33.854 +0530
XYZ
1
Dummy-NW-1
Dummy MG-1
1234aaaa


5f
Attach Complete
2024-05-06 18:26:41.349 +0530
2024-05-06 18:26:41.356 +0530
XYZ
1
Dummy-NW-1
Dummy MG-1
1234aaaa



Can we rollup events data into 24 hours bucket with interval of 5 mins and if 5 mins bucket doesn't have data then it should take the previous value of that bucket data. So the output should look like wgere start_ts is 15:05 and end_ts is 19:05 with 5 mins interval.



bucket
sim_state
device




2024-05-06 15:05:00.000

1


2024-05-06 15:10:00.000

1


2024-05-06 15:15:00.000

1


2024-05-06 15:20:00.000

1


2024-05-06 15:25:00.000

1


2024-05-06 15:30:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 15:35:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 15:40:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 15:45:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 15:50:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 15:55:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:00:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:05:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:10:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:15:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:20:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:25:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:30:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:35:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:40:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:45:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:50:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:55:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:00:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:05:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:10:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:15:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:20:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:25:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:30:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:35:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:40:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:45:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:50:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:55:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:00:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:05:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:10:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:15:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:20:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:25:00.000
0
1


2024-05-06 18:30:00.000
0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 18:35:00.000
0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 18:40:00.000
0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 18:45:00.000
0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 18:50:00.000
0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 18:55:00.000
0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 19:00:00.000
0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 19:05:00.000
0,0,0,1
1




Can some please help me with the query?
I tried with below query:
    WITH buckets AS (
    SELECT
        generate_series(
            '2024-05-06 15:05:00'::timestamp,
            '2024-05-06 19:05:00'::timestamp,
            '5 minutes'::interval
        ) AS bucket
),
events AS (
    SELECT
        bucket,
        COALESCE(
            (SELECT STRING_AGG(
                CASE 
                    WHEN event_name = 'Attach Complete' THEN '1'
                    WHEN event_name = 'Detach' THEN '0'
                    ELSE '-1'
                END,
                ',') 
            FROM tsdb_events 
            WHERE tsdb_events.event_time >= buckets.bucket
            AND tsdb_events.event_time < buckets.bucket + INTERVAL '5 minutes'
            AND tsdb_events.device = '1'),
            LAG(
                (SELECT STRING_AGG(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN event_name = 'Attach Complete' THEN '1'
                        WHEN event_name = 'Detach' THEN '0'
                        ELSE '-1'
                    END,
                    ',') 
                FROM tsdb_events 
                WHERE tsdb_events.event_time < buckets.bucket
                AND tsdb_events.device = '1')
            ) OVER (ORDER BY buckets.bucket)
            -- Default to an empty string if no previous value exists
        ) AS sim_state
    FROM
        buckets 
)
SELECT
    bucket,
    COALESCE(sim_state, '') AS sim_state,
    '1' AS device
FROM
    events
ORDER BY
    bucket;

However output is coming like




bucket
sim_state
device




2024-05-06 15:05:00.000

1


2024-05-06 15:10:00.000

1


2024-05-06 15:15:00.000

1


2024-05-06 15:20:00.000

1


2024-05-06 15:25:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 15:30:00.000

1


2024-05-06 15:35:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 15:40:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 15:45:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 15:50:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 15:55:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:00:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:05:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:10:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:15:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:20:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:25:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:30:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:35:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:40:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:45:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:50:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 16:55:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:00:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:05:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:10:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:15:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:20:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:25:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:30:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:35:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:40:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:45:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:50:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 17:55:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:00:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:05:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:10:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:15:00.000
1,0
1


2024-05-06 18:20:00.000
0
1


2024-05-06 18:25:00.000
0,1,0,0
1


2024-05-06 18:30:00.000
1,0,0
1


2024-05-06 18:35:00.000
1,0,0,0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 18:40:00.000
1,0,0,0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 18:45:00.000
1,0,0,0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 18:50:00.000
1,0,0,0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 18:55:00.000
1,0,0,0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 19:00:00.000
1,0,0,0,0,0,1
1


2024-05-06 19:05:00.000
1,0,0,0,0,0,1
1




Hi - please don’t use images, as your data cannot be copied by anyone who wants to try a solution. Please also format your data as tables so that it is readable

hi @NickW - added data as tables

WITH buckets AS (
    SELECT
        generate_series(
            '2024-05-14 15:05:00'::timestamp,
            '2024-05-14 19:05:00'::timestamp,
            '5 minutes'::interval
        ) AS bucket
),
events AS (
    SELECT
        buckets.bucket as bucket,
        COALESCE(
            STRING_AGG(
                CASE 
                    WHEN tsdb_events.event_name = 'Attach Complete' THEN '1'
                    WHEN tsdb_events.event_name = 'Detach' THEN '0'
                    ELSE '-1'
                END,
                ','
            ) FILTER (WHERE tsdb_events.device = '1'), null) AS sim_state,
            tsdb_events.device as device
    FROM
        buckets 
    LEFT JOIN tsdb_events 
    ON tsdb_events.event_time >= buckets.bucket 
    AND tsdb_events.event_time < buckets.bucket + INTERVAL '5 minutes'
    GROUP BY buckets.bucket,tsdb_events.device
)
SELECT
  bucket, sim_state, value_partition, first_value(sim_state) over (partition by value_partition order by bucket)
FROM (
  SELECT
    bucket,
    sim_state,
    sum(case when sim_state is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by bucket) as value_partition

  FROM events
  ORDER BY bucket ASC
)as q;

This query worked.
